# Why does adding a gradient to text using tailwind only work with the anchor tag?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

I am using next.js with typescript and I am trying to create a text gradient on an h1 element. However, when doing so, it does not work and displays the h1 text as the first color, however, replacing it with an anchor tag fixes it. It does not work with any other type of tag, like p, h2, etc.

This is a starter project and I used npx create-next-app with typescript in order to create it.

This is my page.tsx file:

```
function Projects() {
    return (  
        <h1 className="text-6xl font-bold text-transparent bg-clip-text bg-gradient-to-r from-pink-400 to-purple-600">Hero</h1>
    );
}

export default Projects;
```

I have no idea what is causing the issue, and I have deleted everything from the globals.css file except the tailwind stuff:

my globals.css file:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

[This is what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WduV.png)

[This is what is supposed to happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piWTn.png)

If it helps, this is my tailwind.config.js file:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        'gradient-radial': 'radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
        'gradient-conic':
          'conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: You do not see the effect because the **h1** is a block element and the effect spans the full width of it. Set it as `display:inline-block` for example which makes the element take as much width as the text, and you will see it. Also, to prove  my point further, if you inspect the letters with a color picker, there is a tiny gradient there.

Comment: Yes, basically you want to make the text span the same with than what is considered background, otherwise, if the text is short, the effect spreads in a much larger width. You may answer the Q yourself.